# weird behavior of rviz ros-fuerte

Tags: ros, kinect, rviz, openni, openni.launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

This question is heavily related to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise/) one.
After tons of magic I've been finally able to read depth information from my ASUS kinect.
So, I have to open 1 terminal, print

```
killall XnSensorServer
```

in other terminal I start the camera

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

then when I open rviz in one more terminal I am able to view depth image from the camera. But, *here comes the weird stuff*: if I *move* the camera window in rviz I get an error in roslaunch terminal:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'openni_wrapper::OpenNIException'
  what():  virtual void openni_wrapper::OpenNIDevice::startDepthStream() @ /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-openni-camera-1.8.0/debian/ros-fuerte-openni-camera/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/openni_camera/src/openni_device.cpp @ 257 : starting depth stream failed. Reason: Xiron OS got an event timeout!
[camera_nodelet_manager-2] process has died [pid 20183, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/igor/.ros/log/68736576-b16d-11e1-882b-d0df9aa0a99d/camera_nodelet_manager-2.log].
log file: /home/igor/.ros/log/68736576-b16d-11e1-882b-d0df9aa0a99d/camera_nodelet_manager-2*.log
```

The same if I try to choose the color_image topic from the camera in rviz.
Maybe this would help to localize the bug that definitely is somewhere there.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36043/weird-behavior-of-rviz-ros-fuerte/) by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2012-06-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the last update of ros-fuerte I don't experience this bug anymore.

---

Originally posted by [niosus](https://answers.ros.org/users/2034/niosus/) with karma: 386 on 2012-07-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-09-10**:
I'm still experiencing this behaviour using the current version of ROS Fuerte.